# Disable right click menu in swing spinner component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, spinner

I have a spinner running in JTable and when a user right clicks on it a menu popups with copy, cut, paste choices. My questions is, how can I disable this menu? Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I've never seen this behavour. I would guess you have some custom code somewhere that is doing this. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Alexander interesting idea, can I see that too

Comment: Oh, if my apps did so ;)

Comment: This is no default behavior. Which look and feel are you using?